# FLUTTER ERROR:RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application - ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class

Tags: flutter, runtime-error

I am running my code in VS

I am trying to RUN my FLUTTER app and I keep getting this error: after so many attempts i decided to post it here..

To understand the issue better I'll add all the related code segments down below.Please note I'll add only the related part of the code

The stack trace

```
E/AndroidRuntime(20628): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(20628): Process: com.example.test_proj, PID: 20628
E/AndroidRuntime(20628): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.test_proj.GalleryApp package com.example.test_proj: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.test_proj.GalleryApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~QkNtldeeFc8qkMNrqIHWXg==/com.example.test_proj-fpNR6wn5Zt92y_CLvgBWUA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~QkNtldeeFc8qkMNrqIHWXg==/com.example.test_proj-fpNR6wn5Zt92y_CLvgBWUA==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~QkNtldeeFc8qkMNrqIHWXg==/com.example.test_proj-fpNR6wn5Zt92y_CLvgBWUA==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(20628):        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1466)
E/AndroidRuntime(20628):        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1395)
E/AndroidRuntime(20628):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6720)
E/AndroidRuntime(20628):        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(20628):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2133)
E/AndroidRuntime(20628):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(20628):        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/AndroidRuntime(20628):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime(20628):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
E/AndroidRuntime(20628):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(20628):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/AndroidRuntime(20628):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
E/AndroidRuntime(20628): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.test_proj.GalleryApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~QkNtldeeFc8qkMNrqIHWXg==/com.example.test_proj-fpNR6wn5Zt92y_CLvgBWUA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~QkNtldeeFc8qkMNrqIHWXg==/com.example.test_proj-fpNR6wn5Zt92y_CLvgBWUA==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~QkNtldeeFc8qkMNrqIHWXg==/com.example.test_proj-fpNR6wn5Zt92y_CLvgBWUA==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(20628):        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
E/AndroidRuntime(20628):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime(20628):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(20628):        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
E/AndroidRuntime(20628):        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:52)
E/AndroidRuntime(20628):        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1243)
E/AndroidRuntime(20628):        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1458)
E/AndroidRuntime(20628):        ... 11 more
```

build.gradle file

```
 defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.avinyafoundation.campusapp.dev.mobile"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                'appAuthRedirectScheme': "com.avinyafoundation.campusapp.dev"
        ]
    }
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.avinyafoundation.campusapp.dev.mobile

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.avinyafoundation.campusapp.dev.mobile">
    <application
        android:label="mobile"
        android:name="com.avinyafoundation.campusapp.dev.mobile"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
..
```

I have tried many solutions that i could find on the internet but did not work. Can anyone help me to fix this issue?
Thanks for your time

Comment: i think stack overflow is dead now. will never post a question again